# format ntfs to Journaled HFS+

Tags: macos, formatting, ntfs, mount

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mac: ntfs hard drive not mounted, how to reformat to Journaled HFS+ and keep data](https://superuser.com/questions/224224/mac-ntfs-hard-drive-not-mounted-how-to-reformat-to-journaled-hfs-and-keep-data)

I have recently connected a hard drive to my mac pro and im not able to use it because its formatted in ntfs whilst the other drive containing the OS is formatted to Journaled HFS+. The message im getting says it isnt mounted; can you guys help me by pointing me to the reight resources or explaining what to do.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mac: ntfs hard drive not mounted, how to reformat to Journaled HFS+ and keep data](http://superuser.com/questions/224224/mac-ntfs-hard-drive-not-mounted-how-to-reformat-to-journaled-hfs-and-keep-data) (User was sent to SU and made another thread before his original topic was moved).

Answer (score 0):

Depends - do you want to save the data that is already on the drive?  If not, just go into the Utilities folder in Applications, find the Disk utility.  In it, there is a format option that will allow you to select that drive, destroy the unreadable volume on it - and reformat it whatever Mac-compatible file system you desire.

If you DO want to keep the data, you will need to hook the drive up to a Windows machine, back up the data to a CD or DVD, then wipe out the drive using the directions above, and use the DVD or CD to restore the files to the newly formatted drive.

Comment: I want to keep the data thats on the ntfs drive; can i just image the drive and retrieve the data from the image? if so what tools will i need?